# How to stop Python Crashes on exit

Tags: python, crash, spyder, pythonw

After a script runs, the Python instance crashes.

Error Signature is:

```
AppName pythonw.exe AppVer 0.0.0.0 ModName:ntdll.dll
ModVer 5.2.3790.3959 Offset 00020d8e
```

The script sometimes works fine, then other crashes. It launched from with Spyder.
When launched outside of Spyder, still crashes.

The first run seems to work, but the second gives crashes.

Python version. 
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't given much to go on.

Comment: Do you have an error log/ and information as to what is causing it to crash/ where it crashes?

Comment: Look closer folks. If it says pythonw.exe then it is discarding the traceback. The traceback would point to where to begin debugging. Of course it could still be something to do with incompatible modules that were compiled with the wrong compiler, but a traceback is absolutely essential to get started.

Comment: Crashes when running with pythonw or python, inside or outside spyder. there is a crash. The last line on script is print finished, which it does then crashed. I think it crashed on closing python.... error log? where to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in the NT Kernel Layer DLL which is part of the Windows OS. Most likely causes are an OS bug, or a hardware problem. You might want to go into Windows Update and see if there are any optional updates for hardware that you have installed.

This has nothing directly to do with Python and the best that you could hope to do would be to figure out what part of your script triggers the OS bug, and avoid doing that.

Comment: People don't like it when you don't post code, or tracebacks. It would be -4 without my upvote. You might be able to get help on this at superuser.com because it is an OS kernel error.

Answer (score 8):

When this kind of thing happens, your first move has to be to STOP using pythonw.exe to run the script. Start the script with python.exe so that you get a console window and you can see the traceback message. That will usually tell you what part of the code is causing the crash.

Did you install Spyder using [the Python 2.6 version of the binary](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/detail?name=spyder-2.0.11_py26.exe&can=2&q=)?

Comment: Start the script with python.exe so that you get a console window and you can see the traceback message. That will usually tell you what part of the code is causing the crash.: did that b4 posting, no trace